# React native modal blur/vibrancy on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm trying to build a modal that looks somewhat like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dJva.jpg) using React Native for iOS and Android. Are there any libraries that do blurred/vibrancy overlays? I had a look at the [react-native-blur](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-blur), however unfortunately this is only for iOS. React-native-overlay also has some options for such views, however it also appears to be iOS only.

Is there a library that supports both platforms, or is there a way to use a JS library such as `vibrancy.js` that can be used with React?

Comment: Try this module [react-native-blur](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-blur)

Answer (score 1):

Currently react-native-blur supports blur for Android as well. However a little bit of setup is required. Check out the docs here:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur.

The library also offers the ability to create vibrancy views. Although, at the present (v 3.2.2), vibrancy will only work fo iOS.